# Save Mac Terminal session to text file

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Is there a way of saving the terminal history of a script to file? I know I can do this by Shell > Export Text As... but is there a command (Bash) to do this?

Comment: What is the terminal history of a script? It's output? Would redirecting it to a file with `my_script > output.txt` be enough?

Comment: @patrix My script has a main menu. If the user enters some option, it produces an output. I would like to include an option in the main menu that saves whatever that is on screen to a text file, I meant. Hope that makes it clearer!

Comment: @patrix Basically, the current session.

Comment: "Session", "history" and "content of current screen" are three different things. If you want to have the same as the Export Text as function, it's definitively more than what's on screen :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with the standard unix command [`script(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script) though requires running a subshell under the current shell. That is, start a terminal, and run `script`, issue whatever commands need to be logged, then exit from that shell:

```
$ script
Script started, output file is typescript
$ uptime
11:30  up 22 days, 16:15, 1 user, load averages: 1.43 1.37 1.38
$ exit

Script done, output file is typescript
$
```

Then in the output `typescript` file there should be a record of the shell session run under `script(1)`.

But wait, there's more! With `expect` one can also save a session and possibly replay it. This requires installing `expect` from a ports system (Fink, Homebrew, or here MacPorts) which should install `autoexpect`:

```
$ port installed | grep expect
  expect @5.45.3_0 (active)
$ which autoexpect
/opt/local/bin/autoexpect
$ autoexpect $SHELL
autoexpect started, file is script.exp
$ uptime
 6:47  up 23 days, 11:32, 1 user, load averages: 1.37 1.39 1.33
$ exit
autoexpect done, file is script.exp
$
```

Doing something useful with `script.exp` in turn probably requires knowledge of `expect` and TCL, so this is a more advanced option. (`expect` in particular has a `log_file` option that can be toggled to save everything, but then you'd be writing everything in TCL and not `bash`...)

Otherwise the terminal itself must save the session; `iTerm.app` probably has more options for this (Session -> Log -> Start) than `Terminal.app`.